# intent-filter to catch intents for viewing *.ext files

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, file-extension

I am trying to figure out the intent-filters I need in order to:

view file or content with *.npk extension

I read loads of the stackoverflow articles about intent-filters, but still can't understand what am I missing.

For example when this is my intent-filter, I expect it to catch files with "*.npk" extension. I know about the bug with the patterns, so I added multiple data lines in order to catch paths where there is 0-4 dots before .npk:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\.npk" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.npk" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.npk" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.npk" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.npk" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When I open a file from total commander app it works, and it starts my activity as expected (BTW this works even if I only have one pathPattern=".*\\.npk", so maybe the mentioned bug is fixed in lollipop):

```
{act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.fletech.smartbaby.android.pro/files/npk/animal-water-he.npk typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.fletech.smartbaby.android/.CategorySliderActivity}
```

However I can't make it work from Dropbox app. This is a "captured" intent from logcat. In order to capture it I added android:mimeType="*/*" so I could chose my app, now every file (also .jpg) wants to open my app.

```
{act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/u123456/scratch/apk/nature_0.npk typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x10000003 cmp=com.fletech.smartbaby.android/.CategorySliderActivity (has extras)}
```

I don't understand why the above filter doesn't catch this intent. The only difference I see between the total commander intent and the dropbox intent is the flag, extras which should not make a difference IMHO, and that there are 2 vs 4 dots in the path before the file extension, but my intent filter should take care of it.

Note: I am developing and testing on lollipop, but I would like it to work on api 9+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another long period of trial and error I found the following solution working. I had to add both android:host="*" and android:mimeType="*/*" to the data elements. It seems that there are some inconsistencies in the official android documentation.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.npk" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.npk" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.npk" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.npk" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.npk" />
        </intent-filter>
```